# Android Studio Folder doesn´t get created

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to create a folder on my device and the result isn't as expected.

I do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

My code:

```
public void saveOnDevice(){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/hello");
    boolean x = true;
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        x = myDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if(x) {
        System.out.println("Folder created " + root);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Folder not created" + root);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Folder not created /storage/emulated/0
```

Expected:

```
Folder created /storage/emulated/0
```

I tried this on my Samsung Galaxy S8. I don't have a SD-Card inserted. I don't have the path `/storage/emulated/0` on my device. Why isn't it working and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), you're trying to save to an SD card, you need to use either getFilesDir() or getCacheDir() to save on your [local](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage) device or insert an SD card.

Comment: @MitchellMonarch i get the path and create the file but i cant access it. How can i access it? I want to save mp3 files in this folder. Is there no other solution to create a folder on the local storage without a sd card?

Answer (score 0):

You do have that folder /storage/emulated/0 on your device. You probably just can't see it due to the layer of abstraction when using Samsungs file browser.

You can verify that by using a more advanced file browser such as FX File Explorer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx) and start looking up that path from "System /".

That `root` string won't help you.

Instead you want to do something like this:

```
// create folder "myDir" in internal storage as sub directory of /storage/emulated/0
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myDir");
// create file
File myFile = new File(myDir, "song.mp3");
// get file stream 
FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
```

Then you can simply write your songs content to `fileStream`.

It's a bit confusing that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` actually gives you the *internal* storage location, but it is external to your apps directory which is something like `Android/your.apps.packagename/`.